# DRF custom check_permission not being called

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a custom permission to a view which extends a generic `DetailView`:

```py
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class MyCustomPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return False


class MyView(SomeMixin, DetailView):
    model = MyObject
    template_name = "my_template.html"
    permission_classes = [MyCustomPermission]

    def get_object(self):
        return MyObject.objects.get(id=123)
```

This should always fail, but it doesn't. I can also put a breakpoint in there (e.g. `import pudb; pudb.set_trace()`) but that won't ever get hit either.

I know that `has_object_permission(...)` needs to be explicitely called, but I thought `has_permission(...)` got called when the view first got called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Django generic [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) and expecting to behave as DRF views